# C++ stack using linked lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to implement a simple stack using linked lists. When I run the code below, I get

```
6
<some random integer>
```

I've been looking for my mistake for hours now without success. I guess there is an uninitalized Variable somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node {
    public:
        node operator = (const node&);
        node(int d,node* n): data(d), prev(n) {}
        node(){}
        node* prev;
        int data;
};

node node::operator = (const node &n) {
    node r(n.data, n.prev);
    return r;
}

class stack {
    public:
        stack();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        bool empty();
    private:
        node* top;
};

stack::stack() {
    top = 0;
}

bool stack::empty() {
    return top == 0;
}

void stack::push(int x) {
    node n(x,top);
    top = &n;
}

int stack::pop() {
    if (!empty()) {
        node r = *top;
        //cout << "r.data: " << r.data << endl;
        top = top->prev;
        return r.data;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Stack empty!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    stack a;
    a.push(5);
    a.push(6);
    cout << a.pop() << endl;
    cout << a.pop() << endl;
}
```

Now the thing that totally confuses me, is that when I uncomment the line

```
        //cout << "r.data: " << r.data << endl;
```

for testing purposes, the output changes to

```
r.data: 6
6
r.data: 6
6
```

Why would that happen?

Comment: You should really read about the [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of variables in c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
void stack::push(int x) {
    node n(x,top);
    top = &n;
}
```

Here you create a local variable, and then set `top` to point to that. But when the function returns then the local variable does not exists any more, and `top` points to some memory that is not valid.

You need to create a new `node` on the heap with the `new` operator:

```
void stack::push(int x) {
    node* n = new node(x,top);
    top = n;
}
```

Of course, now you have to make sure the allocated nodes are free'd when your done. This should be done in a destructor in `stack` that pops all nodes, and in `pop` you need to use the `delete` operator to free the memory.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Changed it to: 

    node *n = new node(x,top);
    top = n;

works now.

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is a programming assignment for a class, use  [std::stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/) provided with STL.

Answer (score 0):

```
void stack::push(int x) {
    node n(x,top);
    top = &n;
}
```

Problem with this function is that n has automatic storage duration, and is destroyed after function returns.

Instead, use dynamic allocation:

```
node* n = new node(x, top);
```